# Haskell recursive dictionary function problems

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have been trying to learn Haskell and currently trying to make a recursive "dictionary" or "translator" function.
Basically it should receive an array of stings like and an array of tuples or sting, and return an array of strings that has elements replaced by tuple's 2nd part if it matched 1st one.
So basically from

```
["a", "b", "zz"] [("a", "11"),("b","c")]
```

to

```
["11","c","zz"]
```

Having trouble making it... this is what I have so far:

```
aa (x:xs) (y:ys) = do
    -- iterate through y
    if ys == [] then return(x:xs) else aa (x:xs)(ys)
        -- iterate through x
    if xs == [] then return(x:xs) else aa (xs)(y:ys);

    if x == fst(y) 
    then do 
        putStrLn("Yes");
        return (snd(y):xs);
    else return (x:xs);
```

which worked for 1st element of the array.
I can't seem to figure out how do I make it go through. Also removing putStrLn causes error "mismatched" brackets, why?

While trying to figure it out also tried storing the result, and it didn't work out:

```
aa (x:xs) (y:ys) = do

    if x == fst(y)
    then result <- snd(y):xs
    else result <- x:xs

    return result;
```

resulted in an error "parse error on input '<-' Perhaps this should be in a 'do' block?"

Comment: Once you do find a match, you never recurse  (call aa) again. Also, a much simpler implementation is: put the array of tuples in a dictionary as fst() as key, snd() as value. Then iterate the list (this can be recursive or not) and foreach element, yield the value of that key in the dictionary or the value in the list if there is no such key (that is, dict.getOrDefault(element, element))

Comment: If `ys == []` shouldn't you check if the *entire* list is empty. That being said your code looks imperative, not functional, and you perhaps should make it easier for yourself by first writing a function that can look up a *single* value in the dictionary.

Comment: You also use a lot of `return` and `do`s. These are `Monad` functions. Usually you do not find these very often in pure functions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will look into that stuff

Comment: `return` does not do what you think it does.  How about a game? Never type `return`, forget it exists. Every time you want to type it instead type `pure` and think "I am lifting this value into a richer computation environment". If you don't know what a monad is or which monad you are in then you never even need to type "pure".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not too tricky a problem to solve if we break it down. Firstly we want a function which takes a list of tuples, and a key, and returns the value of that key if it exists in the list.

Fortunately this is already defined for us, with [lookup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup)

It returns a Maybe value. If we don't find it, then we don't need to replace it, so we can simply return the original value. [fromMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) does this for us, it takes a default value and a maybe value, and if the maybe value is a Just, it returns the value in the just.

Now we just need to map over the list, and for each item, replace it with the item in the association list if it exists, or if not, replace it with itself.

And here's the code:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

translator xs ys = map replace xs
    where replace x = fromMaybe x (lookup x ys)
```

Your code has a few issues in that you appear to be trying to use do notation when it's not really needed. When you're a beginner, generally you should just be using do notation in functions where you use IO. If you want to define something to prevent everything being one long statement, you can use where or let.

```
λ> translator ["a", "b", "zz"] [("a", "11"),("b","c")]
["11","c","zz"]
λ>
```